# How to build Webkit for Android?

Tags: android, build, webview, webkit

In my question [How Android webview uses webkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528742/how-android-webview-uses-webkit) I know that `WebViewCore.java` loads **webcore** and **chromium_net**

```
static {
        // Load libwebcore and libchromium_net during static initialization.
        // This happens in the zygote process so they will be shared read-only
        // across all app processes.
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("webcore");
            System.loadLibrary("chromium_net");
       }
}
```

1. Where is `libwebcore.so` and `libchromium_net.so` located?
2. I know that webcore is from [external/webkit source](https://github.com/android/platform_external_webkit/tree/master/Source)? So what is chromium_net?
3. How can I use [webkit source](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit) to build .so file so that I can replace the 2 .so file that come with Android source (I heard that Android uses old webkit version)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, is it OK to include the custom built webkit in my own Android application ?

Comment: There are three individual questions here - please check the StackOverflow guidelines and break this up into single questions that have definite answers.

Comment: @Justicle sorry for that. I think they are related to each other, so I wrap them into a single question

Answer (score -2):

There are several open-source web browsers available for Android, considering your question is probably better that you learn from them instead of us trying to reply to all your questions.

Try [zirco](http://code.google.com/p/zirco-browser/).

Comment: Can you show me some open source web browsers for Android that uses webkit as their engine?

Comment: everyone beside Firefox, basically webkit is the only opensource engine that is popular in the modding community, most of the time this open source browser are a refactoring of the official web-browser, and by the way you can always access the source of all the Android applications in the AOSP project, browser included.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it simply uses the webview that android provides.